# How to set the minimum number of rows of a long table on the start page?

Tags: tables, longtable

There is a long table

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing

%%% Tables.
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
%
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Caption of Table
\usepackage[format=hang,
labelsep = space,
skip=1ex, 
singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

%%% Page
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm, right=15mm}

\begin{document}
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

    \begingroup
    \sisetup{table-column-width=6.5ex}
    \begin{longtable}[l]{@{}c  
            S[table-column-width=11ex,
            table-format= 4.1]
            S[table-format=-3.1]
            S[table-format=-3.1]
            S[table-format= 1.4]
            S[table-format= 1.2]
            S[table-format=-2.1]
            S[table-format=-2.1]
            @{}}
        \caption{--- Caption of long table}
        \label{tableLabel} \\
        \toprule
        \multirow{3}{*}{Date}
        &   {\multirow{3}{*}[1ex]{\makecell{Ratio V/N\\ transactions$^*$\\ EURO}}}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Absolute increases, \\ EURO}}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Coefficients}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Rates of\\ growth \%}} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
        \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
        \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        &   &   {chain}
        &   {base}
        &   {chain}
        &   {base}
        &   {chain}
        &   {base}                                  \\
        \midrule
        {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8}                           \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        %
        \multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation \ref{tableLabel}}                     \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}{*}{Date}
        &   {\multirow{3}{*}[1ex]{\makecell{Ratio V/N\\ transactions$^*$\\ EURO}}}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Absolute \\ increases}}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Coefficients}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Rates of\\ growth \%}} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
        \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
        \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        &   &   {chain}
        &   {base}
        &   {chain}
        &   {base}
        &   {chain}
        &   {base}                                  \\
        \midrule
        {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8}                           \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\footnotesize
            $^*$: Ratio of the volume of, transactions to the number of transactions in EURO}
        &   \multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize Continuation on the next page}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{\footnotesize
            $^*$: Ratio of the volume of, transactions to the number of transactions in EURO}
        \endlastfoot
        %
        30.09.2014  & 1438  & {--} & {--} & {--} & 1 & {--} & {--} \\
        01.10.2014  & 1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
        02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
        03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
        06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
        \addlinespace
        07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
        08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
        09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
        10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
        13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
        \addlinespace
        01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
        02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
        03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
        06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
        07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
        \addlinespace
        08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
        09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
        10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
        13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
        01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
        \addlinespace
        02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
        03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
        06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
        07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
        08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
        \addlinespace
        09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
        10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
        13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
        01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
        02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
        \addlinespace
        03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
        06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
        07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
        08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
        09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
        \addlinespace
        10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
        13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
        01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
        02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
        03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
        \addlinespace
    \end{longtable}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

When the table is moved to a new page, only one row with data can remain on the previous page. You can see it in the picture.

[image]
[image]

I need to leave at least 3 or more lines of data on the previous page, otherwise the table should be completely transferred to a new page.

Comment: Have you tried using non-breaking line breaks for the first three rows?

Comment: No. I did not know about it.
How is this realized?

Comment: Use `\\*` instead of `\\ `.

Comment: @TeXnician Would you like to add an answer or is there a duplicate somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force LaTeX to keep a specific part of a longtable together one has to use `\\*` instead of `\\` which does forbid a page break between those lines. If you do this for the first three rows it should solve your problem.

Please note: Excessive use of this "feature" prevents longtable from breaking which you probably don't want.